# How to increase memory used to back large memory mapped files

Tags: linux, mmap

When I mmap a whole 6.54 GiB file for read only use, it's not using all available memory to cache it. You can see kswapd using a lot of CPU. The resident size is only ~4.4 GB. If I decrease the mapped size to below 4400 MB, then the paging is gone. This is on a Linux, aarch64 board.

```
int fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
size_t file_size=(1LL<<20)*4400;
int8_t*buffer=(int8_t*)mmap(NULL,file_size,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED/*|MAP_HUGETLB*/,fd,0);
if(buffer == MAP_FAILED)
  throw 0;
while(true)
{
  int64_t sum=0;
  for(size_t i=0;i<file_size;i+=8)
    sum+=*(int64_t*)&buffer[i];
  cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

How can I tell Linux to use more memory for the page cache? I thought it can grow to as much as you have free (MemAvailable). Here's /proc/meminfo.

```
MemTotal:        7833640 kB
MemFree:         2383724 kB
MemAvailable:    7006316 kB
Buffers:            1568 kB
Cached:          4574996 kB
```

Comment: I would try mlock(2) and mincore(2).

Comment: Thanks, mlock eliminated the paging for 4500 MiB, but if you try to use more, it hangs and eventually reboots. Maybe that's why it refuses to allow resident set size to get so large, because it's unsafe. Also, I think you have to be root to pin that much memory, which is fine for my purposes.